# Loop through sample files bash

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner so would appreciate help.

I have code to loop through sample names from a sample.txt file and carry out a command.

I get an error to say that the software can't read the files in. I have double checked everything and it all looks fine? The sample.txt consists of a list eg:

```
C1
C2
C3 
etc
```

My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u

input=/fastq_trimmed/;

genome=/GI_1st_pass/

sample_info=/RNAseq/sample.txt

sample_files=($(cut -f 1 "$sample_info"))
for file in ${sample_files[@]}
do
  echo working with "$file"

  STAR2 --genomeDir $genome --readFilesIn $input$file'_fwd_paired.fastq' $input$file'_rev_paired.fastq' 
done;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try double quoting `"${sample_files[@]}"`, `"$genome"`, and make the rest after `--readFilesIn` like `"$input$file"_fwd_paired.fastq "$input$file"_rev_paired.fastq`...

Comment: What do you get from running `bash -x yourscript..sh`?  Does that tell you what the problem is?  What exactly is the error message?  Is the trouble that the generated file name doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Why do you have `set -u`?  That will make your script exit if you try to expand a variable that is not set.

Comment: I tried the double quotes but am still getting the same error: EXITING because of fatal input ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=

Comment: Run the program with `xtrace` on (`-x` option) as @JonathanLeffler suggested.  That will show you all the expansions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @cdarke. I think I've worked out what the problem is but I'm still stumped. So I actually had more lines to the bash script and I was using the backslash \ to carry on the script over several lines but it wasn't reading the newline. Can I clarify that using \ should make the script read the next line as if it's just on one line (btw when I do put the code on one long line it's working.)

Comment: Yes, but the \ must be the final character on the line, there must be no other whitespace which follows except the newline character.  Personally I would avoid using long lines and simplify the command.  Fr example, where you have `$input$file'_fwd_paired.fastq'` I would put that into one variable then use that in the command-line.  It makes it easier to debug as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cdarke. I'm still a beginner so your advice is of great help.